# Spark RDD Memory Footprint

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, memory-footprint

Background:

1, Spark 64 cores (executors), 2 Node, 32 core/each, 100GB Memory/node

2, 1GB Float 2D Binary Array Data

```
[   
 0.2, 0.6 ...
]
```

3, Operation: map each Array cell into a list of tuples, replicated 5 times for each cell, e.g,

```
    ((id0, 0.2),(id1, 0.2), (id2, 0.2),(id3, 0.2),(id4, 0.2), (id5, 0.2), (id6, 0.6) ..... ) 
    id: is calculated based on some standard.
```

From Spark UI, I found that the import data size is 105GB (too large?).

In my guess, 15GB is a rough number.

```
    (1GB Array Data (Float) + 2 GB id (long) ) * 5 = 15GB
    * 5  because that each cell is repeated five times in my flatmap function.
```

How Spark represent these data in memory, why is it so large ?